# Rails 3.2 is not saving dropdown selection in form after clicking edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, save, submit

I have a form with input field and dropdown boxes with data from other tables. (joins)
but now when i submit it is good, but when i want to edit the fields the dropdown fields are empty but the text fields aren't

My form code:

```
<%= form_for @contracten, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @contracten.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@contracten.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this contracten from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @contracten.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div id="forms">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :naam %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :naam %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :omschrijving %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :omschrijving %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :organisatie %><br />
    <%= f.select :organisatieid, options_for_select(@organisaties.map{ |f| [f.naam, f.id] }), :include_blank => true %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :vestiging %><br />
    <%= f.select :vestigingid, options_for_select(@vestigingens.map{ |f| [f.naam, f.id] }), :include_blank => true %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Beheerder %><br />
    <%= f.select :persoonid, options_for_select(@personen.map{ |f| [f.naam, f.id] }), :include_blank => true %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :contractsoort %><br />
    <%= f.select :contractsoortid, options_for_select(@contractsoorten.map{ |f| [f.naam, f.id] }), :include_blank => true %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :datumingang %><br />
    <%= f.datetime_select :datumingang %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :datumeinde %><br />
    <%= f.datetime_select :datumeinde %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :contractduur %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :contractduur, :placeholder => 'in jaren' %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :opzegtermijn %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :opzegtermijn, :placeholder => 'In Maanden' %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :betalingsperiode_eenheid_id %><br>
    <%= f.select :betalingsperiodeeenheidid, options_for_select(@betalingsperiodeeenhedens.map{ |f| [f.omschrijving, f.id] }), :include_blank => true %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :betalingstermijn %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :betalingstermijn %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :pdf %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :pdf %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Toevoegen", :class => 'button3' %>
  </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
<br>
```

screenshot:
[image: form with dropdowns and textareas]

I hope someone know's what the problem.

Comment: please include the code for the form. Also make sure the name in the form fields match the columns name...

Comment: editted my question with the _form.html.erb sorry i forgot that :)

Comment: do you have organisatieid, organisatieid, persoonid, contractsoortid  same name in database?

Comment: yes i have the same names in my database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `:selected => ...` to your `options_for_select` parameters.

E.g:

```
<%= f.select :contractsoortid, 
             options_from_collection_for_select(@contractsoorten, 'id', 'naam',
                                               :selected => @contracten.contractsortid), 
             :include_blank => true %>
```

The changes are actually saved, but when you render the form, the actually selected value must be specified.

Comment: Magic. :) Anyway, I updated to use `options_from_collectio_for_select`, it is a bit more "rails way" than the revious one.

Comment: hmm that does not work i get the error wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)

Comment: You probably left a closing parenthesis somewhere, because no function is called with 1 parameter.

Comment: i don't know what the problem is, but it doesn't matter it's works for now.